# Python: Minimum Convex Polygon?

Tags: python, plot

I've accidentally found an interesting way of representing data in the book: Comparative Vertebrate Neuroanatomy by Ann B. Butler. Below is the image with its description from the book. Does anyone know how to code such a plot in python?

[image: Brain weight as a function of body weight]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the **Convex Hull**.  Many libraries including, for example, [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html), have algorithms to find the Convex Hull.  And then Python has many different libraries for plotting a polygon, including, for example, [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/).

Comment: More precisely, [matplotlib.patches.Polygon](https://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Polygon) is one class that can be used when use `matplotlib`.

Comment: It would be helpful if this answer had an example of using these libaries to plot a minimum convex hull from a collection of points.